301 Redirect blog.example.com to www.example.com/blog using htaccess on Ubuntu/Codeigniter4/Wordpress
I have a blog that is currently hosted on my subdomain and I would like to move it to the /blog subdirectory. The main website uses a CodeIgniter4 framework and the blog uses Wordpress. It is hosted on an Apache server using Ubuntu. I am able to redirect the blog.example.com root to www.example.com/blog, but I am not able to redirect blog.example.com/123 to www.example.com/blog/123
Here is the .htaccess file for the website (the line I added is RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|blog), but I included the main part of the file for reference:
# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
    # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
    # RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to the front controller, index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|blog)
    RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

    # Ensure Authorization header is passed along
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

Here is the htaccess for the blog:
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/blog/$1 [R=301]

And here is the Apache config file for www.example.com:
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin me@example.com
     ServerName www.example.com
     ServerAlias www.example.com

     Protocols h2 http/1.1

     DocumentRoot /var/www/example-website/public

     <Directory /var/www/example-website/public>
          SetEnv website
          Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
     </Directory>

     Alias /blog "/var/www/example-blog/public_html"

     <Directory "/var/www/example-blog/public_html">
          SetEnv blog
          Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog /var/www/example-website/writable/logs/errors.log
     CustomLog /var/www/example-website/writable/logs/access.log combined env=website
     CustomLog /var/www/example-blog/public_html/wp-content/access.log combined env=blog

     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
     RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

For reference, here is the HTTPS config file that gets generated by certbot:
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerAdmin me@example.com
     ServerName www.example.com
     ServerAlias www.example.com

     Protocols h2 http/1.1

     Alias /blog "/var/www/example-blog/public_html"

     <Directory "/var/www/example-blog/public_html">
          SetEnv blog
          Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
     </Directory>

     DocumentRoot /var/www/example-website/public

     <Directory /var/www/example-website/public>
          Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog /var/www/example-website/writable/logs/errors.log
     CustomLog /var/www/example-website/writable/logs/access.log combined env=website
     CustomLog /var/www/example-blog/public_html/wp-content/access.log combined env=blog

     RewriteEngine on
# Some rewrite rules in this file were disabled on your HTTPS site,
# because they have the potential to create redirection loops.

#      RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
#      RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com-0001/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com-0001/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

Also, related to the config file, is there a way to have a separate ErrorLog for the blog?

The apache conf you specify here starts with <VirtualHost *:80> so it's just for HTTP requests. It immediately redirects to HTTPS with that last rewrite rule RewriteRule ^ https:.... Your post doesn't really give much information about the precise behavior you are encountering. It might help to provide the apache conf for requests on port 443 as well (the HTTPS conf), and describe exactly the behavior you are getting (including http vs https redirects) and explain what you don't like about it.

Please re-read the guidance for the tags you've used.  This is clearly a question about system configuration, not about programming, so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  See Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on? for guidance.

The issue is the blog htaccess file. You need to have the Rewrite condition above the directives added by Wordpress. Here is how it should be updated:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

